# Getting internal server error when trying to implement the api

Tags: typescript, rest, nestjs, internal-server-error

i am creating a ninja api with creating the ninjas, updating the ninjas and getting the ninjas by their id and also deleting them as well. I am using nest js for this. When I am trying to send the GET request by id it comes with internal server error. I was thinking that error is coming up because of string type in the parameter but after converting to number it still the same.

Below is the ninja controller code

```
import { Body, Controller, Delete, Get, Param, Post, Put, Query } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateNinjaDto } from './dto/create-ninja.dto';
import { UpdateNinjaDto } from './dto/update-ninja.dto';
import { NinjasService } from './ninjas.service';

@Controller('ninjas')
export class NinjasController {


    constructor(private readonly ninjasService: NinjasService){}
    
    //GET REQUEST  
    @Get()
    getNinjas(@Query('weapons') weapons: 'blades'| 'nunchunks'){
        // const service = new NinjasService();
        return this.ninjasService.getNinjas(weapons)    ;
    }


    @Get(':id')
    getOneNinja(@Param('id') id:string){
        
       return this.ninjasService.getNinja(+id);
    }


    @Post()
    createNinja(@Body() createNinjaDto: CreateNinjaDto){
      return this.ninjasService.createNinja(createNinjaDto);    
    }

    @Put(':id')
    updateNinja(@Param('id') id:string , @Body() updateNinjaDto: UpdateNinjaDto)
    {
        // const idx=Number(id)
       return this.ninjasService.updateNinja(+id , updateNinjaDto);
    }

    @Delete(':id')
    removeNinja(@Param('id') id:string)
    {
        // const idx=Number(id)
        return this.ninjasService.removeNinja(+id);
    
    }


}
```

ninja service code

````
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateNinjaDto } from './dto/create-ninja.dto';
import { UpdateNinjaDto } from './dto/update-ninja.dto';


@Injectable()
export class NinjasService {
    private ninjas= [
        {id:0, name:'NinjaA', weapons: 'blades'},
        {id:1, name:'NinjaB', weapons:'nunchunks'},
    ];

    getNinjas(weapons?: 'blades'|'nunchunks')
    {
        if(weapons){
            return this.ninjas.filter((ninja)=> ninja.weapons === weapons);
        }
        return this.ninjas;
    }

    getNinja(id:number)
    {
        
        const ninja=this.ninjas.find((ninja)=>{
            ninja.id===id
        });
            if(!ninja){
            throw new Error('ninja not found');
          }
        return ninja;
    }

    createNinja(createNinjaDto : CreateNinjaDto)
    
    {
        const newNinja = {
            ...createNinjaDto,
            id: Date.now(),
        };
        this.ninjas.push(newNinja);
        return newNinja;
    }

    updateNinja(id:number, updateNinjaDto: UpdateNinjaDto)
    {
        this.ninjas = this.ninjas.map((ninja)=>{
            if(ninja.id===id)
                {
                    return {...ninja , ...updateNinjaDto};
                }
                return ninja;
        });
         return this.getNinja(id);
    }

    removeNinja(id:number){
         
        const ninjaRemove=this.getNinja(id);
        this.ninjas= this.ninjas.filter((ninja)=>{
            ninja.id!==id
        })
        return ninjaRemove;
    }



}


```
````

Comment: What's the error and stack trace you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

> **ninjas.controller.ts**

NinjasService.getNinja() expects a number, but it's beeing called with a number **OR** NaN.

```
@Get(':id')
getOneNinja(@Param('id') id:string){ // <- param id is a string!
  return this.ninjasService.getNinja(+id); // Probably not a good idea, this could become NaN
}
```

**You need to use a pipe to transform it into an actual number:**

```
import { ParseIntPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

@Get(':id')
getOneNinja(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number){ // <- param id is now a number
  return this.ninjasService.getNinja(id);
}
```

Pipes perform **validation**, and this will skip the handler and throw an error '400 Bad Request' if the client tries to call the endpoint with an id that can't be converted into a number.

> **ninjas.service.ts**

**There is also a problem in your find method.** You forgot to use the word **return** in your comparison. If you open a code block `{}` like this, you always need to manually return. Automatic returns are only valid for direct expressions (without a block).

```
const ninja = this.ninjas.find((ninja) => {
  return ninja.id === id // <- notice the return keyword
});
```

or this:

```
const ninja = this.ninjas.find((ninja) => ninja.id === id); // <- or remove the block
```

#### Why it happened?

Route parameters are always strings. In Javascript, a type mismatch like this will result in NaN, which is not enough to throw an error.

However, you're using this value to perform a comparison with your data object. If this value is NaN, it will never match any number. But even if it is a number, your `array.find` method will never return true, since it's missing a return value.

This is why no ninja will ever be found, and your code is throwing a 'ninja not found' error.

```
const ninja=this.ninjas.find((ninja)=>{
  ninja.id===id // <- missing a return statement
});
if(!ninja){
  throw new Error('ninja not found');
}
```

#### Extra tip: better error handling

Instead of throwing a generic JS error, you can provide a clearer response by throwing a proper HTTP code error. NestJS has classes for all of these, and the one for 'not found' is this:

```
import { NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';

if(!ninja){
  throw new NotFoundException('ninja not found')
}
```